# Erro de Caracteres de entrada

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados

Boa Noite estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro com banco de dados mysql, mas estou passando por dificuldades, estou montando os cruds o crud de exibir dados esta funcionando perfeitamente mas o de inserir estou com problema

public class Produtos_Cn
    {
        public Produtos Obj = new Produtos(); //Puxo a classe Leitora para classe exibição

```
    public DataTable MostrarPodutos()
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable(); //Criando uma tabela nova 
        tabela = Obj.Mostrar(); //O mostrar esta na classe leitora (Segundo passo)
        return tabela;


    }

    public void Iserirdados(String Nome, string Idade, String Endereco, string Tel, string Cel)
    {

        Obj.Insertar(Nome,Convert.ToInt32 (Idade), Endereco,Convert.ToInt32(Tel),Convert.ToInt32(Cel)); //Passa os dados por aqui  //obj.colocar setado na classe Produto

    }
}
```

}

Estou com problema no (Obj.Insertar(Nome,Convert.ToInt32 (Idade), Endereco,Convert.ToInt32(Tel),Convert.ToInt32(Cel));) ele fala que a cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto, alguem pode me ajudar

Comment: Se o dado pode vir errado você não pode converter, tem que tentar fazer um *parse* e só aceitar o valor se ele foi convertido corretamente, tem informações nas perguntas *linkadas*.

Comment: Não entendi direito, se o parse você se refere a conversão de int para string, já tentei ele da erro, você poderia me dar um exemplo do que fazer ?

Comment: è só pesquisar no site, deve ter dezenas de perguntas mostrando.